# I get an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a facebook custom button share code. I getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null in console.

```
    document.getElementById('piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn', 'piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn-2').onclick = function () {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        display: 'popup',
        app_id: '{827182594132839}',
        href: window.fbSheareUrl,
    }, function (response) {
        debugger;
        if (response && !response.error_message) {
            var element = document.getElementById("attach-email");
            element.style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('close','close2').click();
        }
        else {
            var element = document.getElementById("attach-email");
            document.getElementById('close', 'close2').click();
            element.style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('share-poup-text').innerHTML = getLanguageWordByKey('PiggyBankShareUnsuccessfulPopUp');
            element.classList.remove("mystyle");
            document.getElementById('piggy-share-icon').classList.remove('email-success');
            document.getElementById('piggy-share-icon').classList.add('email-failed');

        }
    });
}
```

scrtipt is implimented in the end of the html document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your first line:

```
document.getElementById('piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn', 'piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn-2')
```

`document.getElementById()` only supports one single ID at a time.

Use `document.querySelectorAll()` if you want to target multiple IDs instead, which will return a list of nodes with the specified IDs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Alternativly, if it is possible you can also add a common class to your elements and target that class with `document.getElementsByClassName()`, which will return a list of nodes with that class:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

For your example:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn, #piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn-2');

Array.from(buttons).forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
         FB.ui({
          method: 'share',
          display: 'popup',
          app_id: '{827182594132839}',
          href: window.fbSheareUrl,
      }, function (response) {
          debugger;
          if (response && !response.error_message) {
              var element = document.getElementById("attach-email");
              element.style.display = "block";
              document.getElementById('close','close2').click();
          }
          else {
              var element = document.getElementById("attach-email");
              document.getElementById('close', 'close2').click();
              element.style.display = "block";
              document.getElementById('share-poup-text').innerHTML = getLanguageWordByKey('PiggyBankShareUnsuccessfulPopUp');
              element.classList.remove("mystyle");
              document.getElementById('piggy-share-icon').classList.remove('email-success');
              document.getElementById('piggy-share-icon').classList.add('email-failed');

          }
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn', 'piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn-2').onclick = function ()

Comment: Are you handeling the the fact that you get a list of buttons now, as opposed to a single one? See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/pyfw7td0/1/

Answer (score 0):

At once you can get a single element using `document.getElementById`. So you can keep the `id` of the elements inside an array and attach event listener to it

```
['piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn', 'piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn-2'].forEach(function(item){
 document.getElementById(item).onclick==//rest of code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickfnc = function() {

}

document.getElementById('piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn').onclick =clickfnc 
document.getElementById('piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn-2').onclick =clickfnc
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` has only one parameter, you need to change this in your code:

```
document.getElementById('piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn').onclick = function;
document.getElementById('piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn-2').onclick = function;


// Maybe you will prefer to use Jquery which you can use:

$('#piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn, #piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn-2').on('click', function() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` supports only one parameter, so you can get only one element back.

So either you get your elements one by one like this:

```
document.getElementById('piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn').onclick = function() { // stuff }
document.getElementById('piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn-2').onclick = function() { // stuff }
```

or you do it via `querySelectorAll()` which supports more than just one parameter.

```
var elements = document.querySelector('#piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn, #piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn-2');
```

**But** now you can't just add `onclick` at the end of the query because `querySelectorAll()` returned multiple elements, a so called `NodeList`. Because of that, you will need to iterate over your collection called `elements`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].onclick = function() { // stuff }
}
```